# java.lang.NullPointerException on a simple replaceAll()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, replaceall

I try to write a simple strin replace in java. This is java code. In my test enviroment (linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, tomcat) work great. In production enviroment it cause null pointerexception.

How to avoid this....in System.out the string is correctly dispalyed. The error is in line

```
fo=fo.replaceAll("##idEelemento##", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString());
```

This is the class:

```
    /**
     * 
 */
package mdtFOP;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.model.FileInfo;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentReader;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentWriter;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.ResultSet;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;

/**
 * @author marcello
 *
 */
public class fopMDT {
    private static String fo="";

    /** 
     * 
     */
    public fopMDT() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void GenerateLabelPaper(NodeRef nodeRef){

        ContentReader reader=null;
        System.out.println("MDT - Begin Generate label paper procedure . Class: mdtFOP. Method : GenerateLabelPaper(nodeRef) ...");
        if(mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(nodeRef).isFolder()==true){
            System.out.println("MDT - Try to generate A4 QR label PDF file for just created folder.");
            System.out.println("MDT - Loading mdtQR stylesheet for FO transformations");

            try {
                System.out.println("MDT - Reading content of barcodeFile XML file");
                String barcode= readBarcodeXML();
                System.out.println("MDT - Locate and Iterate trought fo files in mdtAdmin site");
                ResultSet fopFolder = mdt.mdtBehaviours.searchService.query(mdt.mdtBehaviours.storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_XPATH, "/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mdtadmin/cm:documentLibrary/cm:xmlTemplate/cm:FOP/cm:fo");
                List<FileInfo> foFiles = mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.listFiles(fopFolder.getNodeRef(0));
                System.out.println("MDT - find " + foFiles.size() +" .fo files in mdtAdmin site folder: " +mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(fopFolder.getNodeRef(0)).getName());
                for (FileInfo foFile:foFiles){System.out.println("MDT - " + foFile.getName());}
                for (FileInfo foFile:foFiles){
                    System.out.println("MDT - Begin label creation for file "+ foFile.getName()+". Read content...");
                    reader = mdt.mdtBehaviours.contentService.getReader(foFile.getNodeRef(), ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
                    fo = reader.getContentString();
                    System.out.println("MDT - DEBUG - fo content: " + "\r" + fo);
                    System.out.println("MDT - Inject folder data before PDF creation from folder: " + mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(nodeRef).getName());
                    System.out.println("MDT - Inject idElemento: " + mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString());
                    fo=fo.replaceAll("##idEelemento##", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString());
                    System.out.println("MDT - Inject descrizione: " + mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                    fo=fo.replaceAll("##descrizione##", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                    System.out.println("MDT - Inject articolo: "+ mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                    fo=fo.replaceAll("##articolo##", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                    System.out.println("MDT - Inject barcode data before PDF creation...");
                    fo=fo.replaceAll("<fo:inline>mdtQRCODE</fo:inline>", barcode.replaceAll("MDTQRMDTQR", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString()));
                    String tempFileName = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID())+".fo";
                    System.out.println("MDT - Begin fo transfomation on disk for file: " + foFile.getName());
                    try{
                        System.out.println("MDT - TempFileName: " + tempFileName);
                        File tempFile = new File(tempFileName);
                        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(tempFile);
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter (file);
                        out.write(fo);
                        out.close();
                        System.out.println("MDT - Starting FOP from command line: ");
                        Process fop;
                        String fopCommand = "/opt/fop-1.1/fop -fo "+tempFileName+" -pdf "+tempFileName+".pdf";
                        System.out.println("MDT - " + fopCommand);
                        fop= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fopCommand);
                        int fopExit =fop.waitFor();
                        if (fopExit==0){
                            System.out.println("MDT - Conversion with FOP terminate WITHOUT error.");
                            QName contentQName = QName.createQName("{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content");
                            FileInfo pdfFile = mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.create(nodeRef,"QR-"+tempFileName+"-"+mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString()+".pdf", contentQName);
                            NodeRef pdf = pdfFile.getNodeRef();
                            ContentWriter writer = mdt.mdtBehaviours.contentService.getWriter(pdf, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
                            System.out.println("MDT - Put PDF label file, " +pdfFile.getName()+" in MDT folder: " + mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(nodeRef).getName() );
                            writer.setMimetype("application/pdf");
                            writer.guessEncoding();
                            tempFile= new File(tempFileName+".pdf");
                            writer.putContent(tempFile);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("MDT - Something went wrong during FOP conversion: error Stack: "+ e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        System.out.println("MDT - Delete .fo and .pdf temporary files from disk.");
                        File f = new File(tempFileName);
                        if (f.exists()){f.delete();};
                        f=  new File(tempFileName+".pdf");
                        if (f.exists()){f.delete();};   
                        System.out.println("MDT - Temporary file deleted");

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("MDT - Something went wrong in FOP conversion routine: error Stack: "+ e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else { System.out.println("MDT - Skip QR creation on this behaviours because node is type:content");
        }
    }





public static String readBarcodeXML(){
    ContentReader reader=null;
    ResultSet barcodeConfigFile= mdt.mdtBehaviours.searchService.query(mdt.mdtBehaviours.storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_XPATH, "/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mdtadmin/cm:documentLibrary/cm:xmlTemplate/cm:FOP/cm:barcodeConfig.properties");
    reader = mdt.mdtBehaviours.contentService.getReader(barcodeConfigFile.getNodeRefs().get(0), ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
    String barcodeXMLFileName = reader.getContentString();
    System.out.println("MDT - Barcode file name from : "+ mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(barcodeConfigFile.getNodeRef(0)).getName());

    ResultSet barcodeFile= mdt.mdtBehaviours.searchService.query(mdt.mdtBehaviours.storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_XPATH, "/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mdtadmin/cm:documentLibrary/cm:xmlTemplate/cm:FOP/cm:"+barcodeXMLFileName);
    System.out.println("MDT - Using Barcode file name : "+ mdt.mdtBehaviours.fileFolderService.getFileInfo(barcodeFile.getNodeRef(0)).getName());
    reader = mdt.mdtBehaviours.contentService.getReader(barcodeFile.getNodeRef(0), ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
    String barcode = reader.getContentString();
    System.out.println("MDT - DEBUG : QR barcode XML file content: " + "\r" + barcode);
    return barcode;
}



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: so, you know in which line the error is. have you figured out which variable isn't referencing to a value? that's the first step to take here.

Comment: And can you reproduce it in *less* than 130 lines? I suspect that 90% of the code in the question is irrelevant.

Comment: it's simple: your fo is null, or mdt is null, or mdt.mdtBehaviours is null, or  mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService is null, or mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_NAME) is null, or something inside getProperty method is null

Answer (score 0):

Put a `null` check before applying the method..

```
if(fo!=null)
 fo=fo.replaceAll("##idEelemento##", mdt.mdtBehaviours.nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef,      ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString());
}
```

Comment: sure it is fo that is null?